# Coordinate descent for Lasso, Question about algorithm

Tags: algorithms, optimization, machine-learning, linear-algebra, gradient-descent

[image]

I'm not sure why the algorithm computes $c_k$ with $\sum_{j \neq k} w_j x_{i, j}$. Why does one need to ignore the $k^{th}$ feature here? I'm not sure how this is derived. Is this the result of taking the gradient with respect to the $k^{th}$ feature?

Also what exactly is $a_k$ and $c_k$?

Comment: I suspect you will need to give us some context: e.g., to tell us what the notation represents, and where you're reading this.  Please credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: You could also formally state the problem you are trying to optimize. I suspect that it's the least squares regression with Lasso regularization, but the update equations are not what I would expect.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [stats.se], where it might have already been answered: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123672/coordinate-descent-soft-thresholding-update-operator-for-lasso.